# cmake: default include path on unix

Tags: path, include, cmake, portability

I'm using cmake and make to compile a project using an external library (speex).
This library is found by the `find_library` command in my `CMakeLists.txt`.
The only problem is: the default include path of cmake does not include `/usr/local/include/`, that is the location of speex's headers.

I do not want to add `/usr/local/include/` to the search path in the `CMakeLists.txt` because it would (I suppose) generate an error on windows where such path doesn't exist. 
Moreover, that would be a dirty trick, I'm not quite fond of this solution.

Do you know a solution to this problem which would be portable and clean ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a full-blown speex find module, either created from scratch, or based on something found with http://www.google.com/search?q=findspeex.cmake

Answer (score 0):

Punt the configuration to the user via the command line, e.g.

```
cmake -DSPEEX_PATH=/usr/local/include
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PATH` argument of `find_library` to specify other places to search. If the path doesn't exist it shouldn't produce an error.